# Shock/Isolation mounting under tension

Tags: structural-engineering, structures, vibration, shock

I want to secure a box (roughly 20kg in total) that contains electronic equipment to the underside of a flat steel structure. We can weld onto the underside.

The steel structure has a high chance of receiving mechanical impacts from above (for example, large rocks falling onto it), so I'd like to find ways to dampen the mechanical shock and vibration reaching the box.

I have seen shock mounts/isolation mounts before (like moulded rubber mounts), but they seem to be designed for supporting objects that rest on top of the mount -- in other words, the mount is designed to be under compression.

What options do I have if the object is "hanging" from the mount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use U brackets with the tops of the U welded to the table underside and flatten the bottom of the U to provide the support - then the vibration mounts can be in compression also side supports can be used to minimize the sidways movement.